# How to parse a JSON with 2 json merged in one

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, eclipse

I have this JSON:

```
[{"id_alumno":"109","nombre":"Cristian","apellidos":"Ari\u00f1o Garc\u00eda"},
{"id_alumno":"110","nombre":"Amanda","apellidos":"Barbastro Cauh\u00e9"},
{"id_alumno":"111","nombre":"Manuel","apellidos":"Barcel\u00f3 Borrell"},
{"id_alumno":"112","nombre":"Alejandro","apellidos":"Bueno Bel\u00edo"},
{"id_alumno":"113","nombre":"Alba","apellidos":"Casanova Alquillu\u00e9"},
{"id_alumno":"114","nombre":"Gema","apellidos":"Cortijo Romance"},
{"id_alumno":"115","nombre":"Raquel","apellidos":"De la Fuente Tirado"},
{"id_alumno":"116","nombre":"\u00c1lvaro","apellidos":"Del ni\u00f1o Jes\u00fas Mu\u00f1oz"},
{"id_alumno":"117","nombre":"Alejandro","apellidos":"Escudero Cerd\u00e1"},
{"id_alumno":"118","nombre":"Olaya","apellidos":"Fern\u00e1ndez Luengo"},
{"curso":"2","clase":"B","asignatura":"Matem\u00e1ticas"}]
```

It is a JSON with 2 tables joined. One of them has "id_alumno", "nombre" and "apellidos" and the other one "curso", "clase" and "asignatura"

And i have this code:

static class Tarea1 extends AsyncTask>
    {
        Context contexto;
        ListView list;
        InputStream is;
        ArrayList listaalumnos = new ArrayList();

```
    public void cargarContenido (Context contexto)
    {
        this.contexto= contexto;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayAdapter<mostrar_alumnos> doInBackground(ListView... params)
    {
        list = params[0];
        String resultado = "fallo";
        mostrar_alumnos alum;
        mostrar_curso_clase_asignatura asign;



        HttpClient cliente = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String URL = "http://"+ip_conexion.IP_Server+"/android/sesion_profesor.php?dia_semana="+dia_semana+"&campo_hora="+campo_hora+"&id_usuario="+id_usuario+"";

        Log.i("httpget", URL);
        HttpGet peticionGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try{
            HttpResponse response = cliente.execute(peticionGet);
            HttpEntity contenido = response.getEntity();
            is = contenido.getContent(); 
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader buferlector = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String linea = null;
        try{
            while((linea = buferlector.readLine())!=null)
            {
                sb.append(linea);
            }
        }catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            is.close(); 
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        resultado = sb.toString(); 
        Log.d("Debug", "Resultado: " + resultado);


        try{
            JSONArray arrayJson = new JSONArray(resultado);

            for(int i= 0; i<arrayJson.length()-1;i++){ 
                JSONObject objetoJson = arrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
                alum = new mostrar_alumnos(objetoJson.getInt("id_alumno"), objetoJson.getString("nombre"), objetoJson.getString("apellidos"));
                JSONObject objetoJson2 = arrayJson.getJSONObject(arrayJson.length()-1);
                String asignatura = new mostrar_curso_clase_asignatura(objetoJson2.getInt("curso"), objetoJson2.getString("clase"), objetoJson2.getString("asignatura")).toString();
                //mTxtView1.setText(asignatura);
                listaalumnos.add(alum); 

            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<mostrar_alumnos> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<mostrar_alumnos>(contexto, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaalumnos); //Contexto de ver clientes (Muestra la lista con los datos de clientes que le he pasado

        return adaptador; 
            }

    public class Pair
    {
        public ArrayAdapter<mostrar_alumnos> result;
        public String asignatura;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Pair p) 
    {
        list.setAdapter(p.result);
        mTxtView1.setText(p.asignatura);
        }

    }
```

The problem is the logcat says:

```
01-27 10:54:55.590: W/System.err(830): org.json.JSONException: No value for id_alumno
01-27 10:54:55.650: W/System.err(830):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
01-27 10:54:55.650: W/System.err(830):  at org.json.JSONObject.getInt(JSONObject.java:444)
01-27 10:54:55.650: W/System.err(830):  at com.example.proyectofin.Alumnos$Tarea1.doInBackground(Alumnos.java:158)
01-27 10:54:55.730: W/System.err(830):  at com.example.proyectofin.Alumnos$Tarea1.doInBackground(Alumnos.java:1)
```

Why doesn´t read id_alumno??

Any help, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of json array,

```
{"curso":"2","clase":"B","asignatura":"Matem\u00e1ticas"}
```

when your i is the last element, you'll get an error, you should check it before reading.

your condition should be like

```
for(int i= 0; i<arrayJson.length() -1 ;i++){
```

Comment: +1, but it may be better to come up with a more robust method of seeing what kind of row this is. For instance, checking if it contains a key `"id_alumno"` or `"curso"` (you can use [`JsonObject.has`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String) for that).

Comment: I couldn't agree more unless you exactly get this list all the time and you are %100 sure that last element of the list will be different. such as you get your list and add a summary in Json.

Comment: Now, it doesn´t give that problem but in the Activity, doesn´t show the TextView and List from onPostExecute...

Comment: you have list and empty textview or you don't have list at all? if your textview is empty, you need to override toString() in your custom class mostrar_alumnos

Comment: @nr4bt alum is already a mostrar_alumnos class. For that, i can´t convert toString. Before i merged the another table, it was showed corrected on Activity.

Comment: It sounds like the issue you're having now is unrelated to the original one. I would recommend trying for a few minutes to solve it, and if you're still stuck, post a new question. But try to do it yourself, first -- the effort results in more learning. It pays off in the long run. :)

Comment: I totally agree with @yshavit

Comment: @yshavit I´ve already solved it. It was a problem with the Pair and extends Asyntask. Thanks!